# OpenGL texture gets mirrored

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

So I am trying to render my texture and i know it works, however when i run my program it renders like this:

[Mirrored texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOxIX.png)

my code to set the texture coordinates is here:

```
Vertex vertices[] =
{
    //POSITION                      //COLOR                         //Texture Co-ordinates
    glm::vec3(-.5f, .5f, 0.f),      glm::vec3(1.f, 0.f, 0.f),       glm::vec2(0.f, 1.f), // [R]
    glm::vec3(-.5f, -.5f, 0.f),     glm::vec3(0.f, 1.f, 0.f),       glm::vec2(0.f, 0.f), // [G]
    glm::vec3(.5f, -.5f, 0.f),      glm::vec3(0.f, 0.f, 1.f),       glm::vec2(1.f, 0.f), // [B]
    glm::vec3(.5f, .5f, 0.f),       glm::vec3(1.f, 1.f, 0.f),       glm::vec2(1.f, 1.f)  // [Y]

};
```

These are my indices:

```
GLuint indices[] = 
{ 
    0, 1, 2, // Triagle 1
    0, 2, 3  // Triangle 2
};
unsigned noOfIndices = sizeof(indices) / sizeof(GLuint); // Calculate the number of Indices
```

I call my image through my header file:

```
// TEXTURE VALUES //
    int imgWidth = 0, imgHeight = 0;

    unsigned char* image = stbi_load("images/letterCube.png", &imgWidth, &imgHeight, NULL, STBI_rgb_alpha);
```

I generate my texture here:

```
glGenTextures(1, &texture0); // Generate Texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture0); // Bind Texture

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT); // Set Texture Params (Wrap S = X)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT); // Set Texture Params (Wrap T = Y)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR); // A type of anti-ailiasing (magnificaiton)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR); // A type of anti-ailiasing (minificaiton)

    if (image)
    {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, imgWidth, imgHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D); // Clones image for different resolutions
    }
    else
    {
        GE_CORE_ERROR("Texture loading failed");
    }

    glActiveTexture(0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    stbi_image_free(image);
```

in my update function I activate my textures:

```
    glUseProgram(core_program);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(core_program, "texture0"), 0);
    // ACTIVATE TEXTURE
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture0);
```

In my `fragment_core.glsl` file I have this:

```
#version 440

in vec3 vs_position;
in vec3 vs_color;
in vec2 vs_texturePoints;

out vec4 fs_color;

uniform sampler2D texture0;
void main()
{
    //fs_color = vec4(vs_color, 1.f);
    fs_color =  texture(texture0, vs_texturePoints) *  vec4(vs_color, 1.f); 
}
```

I am trying to render the texture correctly however it seems like it mirrors from the other triangle. Is it a co-ordinates problem or am i missing the obvious?

Comment: I swapped all the texture components. Works but its mirrored

Comment: The issue seems to be that you look at the back of the geometry. You have to change to the view matrix or rotate the model 180° degrees around the view space y axis. Do you use `glm::lookAt`?

Comment: Pls, show VB initialization code and vertex shader. Also, you could try to make frame capture (in RenderDoc, GPA or what do you have on your platform) and take a look at what you have from an API point of view.